# I need to set an activity if the customer is created or updated but it is not working in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, customer, event-observer, save

**events.xml** (path : app/code/vendor/module/etc/frontend)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="customer_save_die" instance="vendor\module\Observer\AfterCustomer" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**AfterCustomer.php** (path : app/code/vendor/module/Observer/)

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AfterCustomer implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    /**
     * customer register event handler
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $file = fopen("var/test/test.txt", "w") or die ("die")
        fwrite($file, "test");
        fclose($file);

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

can you change your event as following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="customer_save_die" instance="vendor\module\Observer\AfterCustomer" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Let me know if further help required.

Comment: Is the file structure is correct for events.xml

Comment: HI, @parulThakkar it is not working is there any other mistake done it this file

Comment: run php bin/magento setup:di:compile and php bin/magento cache:flush